# Drop Down(typeahead.js) with Bootstrap tags doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

i need to use typeahead.js with bootstrap.taginput,
for product input field.

```
$('.product').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
     source: function (query, process) {
        return $.getJSON(
            '<?php echo site_url("ajax/get_products"); ?>',
            { query: query },
            function (data) {
                return process(newData);
            });
        alert(newData);
    }
  }
});
```

> This is my return data format.

```
{
"1":{"id":"1","value":"Banana"},
"2":{"id":"2","value":"Dell Laptop"},
"3":{"id":"3","value":"Rent A car Management System"}
}
```

no luck ,neither drop down appears nor inputTags works.

> files i added in the following order,

bootstrap-tagsinput.css
typeahead.jquery.js
bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js

Should i need extra css or js files to include or do i have any other issue like  data format etc.

Comment: can you please a sample like this http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/pegp21r7/5/ ?

Comment: like [this](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)